# Toggle/click img to hide/show carousel

Tags: jquery

I have a nav bar with with an li id of "MyMonsters" that is an img that i want clicked to show/hide a div named "botScroll" which is a carousel.

I have tried this that makes the carousel slide up on click but wont go back down when clicked.

```
$("#MyMonsters").click(function() {
        var effect = 'slide';
        var options = { direction: 'down' };
        var duration = 700;
        $('#botScroll').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

I'm new to posting so apologies if i have failed to display something correctly. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys i managed to fix my problem and also learned different ways to achieve what i wanted. 

It was the way that i had written my CSS caused it not to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if your looking for the element to stay hidden on toggle or if you want the regular toggle functionality. Either way if your looking for a slide effect you could look into [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) an implementation might look something like this:

```
$( "#MyMonsters" ).click(function() {
  $( "#botScroll" ).slideToggle( 700 );
});
```